# How to display Google map with response results from Google Directions API in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, google-maps

I have made a server side request to the Google Directions API using the HTTParty gem and am getting back a normal response in JSON.

I was wondering which API I am supposed to use to display the map. The Directions API docs do not specify. Apologies in advance as this is my first time developing with Google API's.

All other documentation I have read shows how to avoid getting the data from the Directions API, I want to use the Directions API.

**Request**

```
@response = HTTParty.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=#{params[:search][:origin]}&destination=#{params[:search][:destination]}key=#{ENV["google_api_key"]}")
```